# Python - For every value in text file?

Tags: python, file, text

With the code I am writing, I have split a text file up using commas, and now for each value in there, I want to make it an integer. I have tried splitting the text file and then turning it into an integer but that would not work. Is there any way of saying for all values in a file, do a certain thing? Also, the amount of values isn't concrete, it depends on the user of the programme (it is a 'shopping list' programme.
My current code:

```
TotalCOSTS=open("TotalCOSTS.txt","r")
Prices=TotalCOSTS.read()

print(Prices)
Prices.strip().split(",")
IntPrices=int(NewPrices)
print(len(IntPrices))

if len(IntPrices)==1:
    print("Your total cost is: "+IntPrices +" Pounds")
elif len(IntPrices)>1:
    FinalTotal = sum([int(num) for num in IntPrices.split(",")])
    print("Your total cost is: "+ FinalTotal +" Pounds")
```

Prices is the file that the values are contained in, so I've stripped it of whitespace and then split it. That is where I need to continue on from.
Thank you xx

Answer (score 1):

```
results = [int(i) for i in results]
```

python 3 you can do:

```
results = list(map(int, results))
```

Comment: Why you are not suggesting list comprehension in python 3? Any specific reason?

Comment: The list comp should work with both.  I'm not certain but I think in 3 the map method is faster. I'm primarily a 2.7 dev so don't count on that as gospel.  In py 2 it would be `results = map(int, results)`

Answer (score 0):

1. NewPrices isn't defined in your code example
2. split() returns a list

The most straight-forward way to accomplish what you are trying to do is the following:

```
total = sum([int(x) for x in TotalCOSTS.read().split(',') if x.isdigit() == True])
```

But this makes some super-simplifying assumptions which won't be accurate all of the time. For example, if something costs $2.99, int() will cast this to 3. Overall, you want to consider the price in terms of cents (idk which currency you are using, but in USD, 100 cents = 1 dollar) so that $2.99 = 299 cents.

So really, you want something like this:

```
total = sum([float(x)*100 for x in TotalCOSTS.read().split(',') if x.isnumeric() == True])/100
```